# Javascript: Change TD color based on TD TITLE value

Tags: javascript, css

I have a requirement to change table data colors based on timestamp in title attribute. For example, from below values,

- if the "deployed on" < 1 hour TD bg color must be in red, else
- if the "deployed on" < 24hrs TD bg color must be in green, else
- if "Deployed on" < 1week bd color should show in grey. like that:

```html
<tr>
  <td title="Deployed on :Wed Mar 25 2015 10:00:00 UTC| check performed on: Wed Feb 14 2015 23:34:00 UTC ">Version 4.0</td>
  <td title="Deployed on :Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 |check performed on: Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 ">version 8.3.2</td>
  <td title="None">None</td>
</tr>
```

Let me know if any thing else required.
FYI, Im using Django & bootstrap css.

Many Thanks

Edit: Date format is fixed: "Deployed on :Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 "

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Not possible with pure CSS

Comment: Im sorry the html code got removed. here it is.......         <tr> 
    <td title="Deployed on :Wed Mar 25 2015 10:00:00 UTC| check performed on: Wed Feb 14 2015 23:34:00 UTC "> Version 4.0 </td>
    <td title="Deployed on :Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 |check performed on: Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 "> version 8.3.2</td>
    <td title="None"> None</td> 
    </tr>

Comment: I can see 2 timestamps. Can you specify which one are you looking for?

Comment: Set the date timestamp as a millisecond value as `data-time` attribute of `td`. This way it will be possible to help you with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You an try something like this if you use title:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    var title = td[i].getAttribute("title").split("|");
    var titleObj = {}
    title.forEach(function(item) {
      var o = item.split(':');
      var retObj = {};
      if (o.length > 1)
        titleObj[o[0].trim()] = new Date(o[1]);
    });

    if (titleObj["Deployed on"])
      td[i].className = titleObj["Deployed on"].getMonth() < 2 ? "red" : "blue";
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td title="Deployed on :Wed Mar 25 2015 10:00:00 UTC| check performed on: Wed Feb 14 2015 23:34:00 UTC ">Version 4.0</td>
    <td title="Deployed on :Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 |check performed on: Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 ">version 8.3.2</td>
    <td title="None">None</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

@Gurvinder's suggestion of moving date to `data`. This is more ideal and scalable approach

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    var deployEdOn = td[i].getAttribute("data-deployed-on")? new Date(td[i].getAttribute("data-deployed-on")):undefined;
    if (deployEdOn)
      td[i].className = deployEdOn.getMonth() < 2 ? "red" : "blue";
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td 
        title="Deployed on :Wed Mar 25 2015 10:00:00 UTC| check performed on: Wed Feb 14 2015 23:34:00 UTC " 
        data-deployed-on="Wed Mar 25 2015 10:00:00 UTC">Version 4.0</td>
    <td 
        title="Deployed on :Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 |check performed on: Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016 " 
        data-deployed-on="Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016">version 8.3.2</td>
    <td 
        title="None">None</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice guys... I will try it. Date Format is fixed, not in two formats as I mentioned above. Sorry for that.... Deployed on :Mon Feb 15 06:05:05 UTC 2016

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rajesh & Gurvinder. Finally with your help it is solved like this

```
    window.onload = function() {
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        var deployed = td[i].getAttribute("title")
        if (deployed){
        if (deployed.indexOf("Deployed on:") >= 0 )
        {
            var title = td[i].getAttribute("title").split("|")[0];
                var titledate = new Date(title.split("Deployed on:")[1]);
        var datem = titledate.getTime()
        var d = new Date();
        var diff = (d.getTime() - datem)

        if (diff < 3600000 ){
                td[i].className = "onehour";
                }
        if (diff < 18000000 && diff > 3600000 ){
                td[i].className = "halfday";
                }
        if (diff < 86400000 && diff > 18000000){
                td[i].className = "oneday";
                }
        if (diff < 604800000 && diff > 86400000){
                td[i].className = "oneweek";
                }
        }
        }
        }
}
```